# merging two lists results in shorter length

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
List_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 158, 159, 160]
List_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 98, 99]
```

The length of `List_1` is `160` and the length of `List_2` is `99`. Now I want to add `List_2` exactly after `List_1` suth that:

```
List_new == [1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 160, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 98, 99]
```

I use two codes separately, but the weird thing is that the length of my `List_new` is less than the sum of lengths `List_1` and `List_2`:

```
List_new = List_1 + List_2
```

&

```
 List_new = List_1.append(List_2)
```

Can anyone help me understand what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: can you share the new length and the resultant list for a better answer

Comment: It works: `assert len(List_1+List_2) == 160+99`, regarding the second option, I think you were looking for `extend`: `List_1.extend(List_2) ; assert len(List_1) == 160+99`

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible. `List_1 + List_2` works and `List_1.append(List_2)` doesn't work at all. Neither of those create a list smaller than expected.

Answer (score 0):

`List_1.extend(List_2)` or `List_1 + List_2` either of these should work.
But when you do `List_new = List_1.append(List_2)`, the value of `List_new` becomes `None`
So it will throw error when you apply `len` on a `None` type object. I dont understand how were you able to compute the length of `List_new` in the code snippet you posted

Answer (score 0):

The length of the list differs, as `.append(x)` adds `x` as a single element to the list while `+` or `.extend(x)` opens up the elements of `x`. `len` just counts the elements of a list without looking at the `len` of the elements themselves.

Consider two lists:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

`.append` and `.extend` commands change their object inplace and do not return anything (`None`)

```py
print(a.append(b))
print(a)

# None
# [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]

print(a.extend(b))
print(a)

# None
#[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 4, 5, 6]
```

If you want to append or extend without manipulating the original data, you can use the following:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

# Append
c = a + [b] # Note the [] around b.
# + will open up the [] and treat b as single element
print(c)
# [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]


# extend
d = a + b
print(d)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

print(a)
print(b)

#[1, 2, 3]
#[4, 5, 6]

# None
#[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6], 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code: `List_1.append(List_2)` just adds all items of `List_2` in `List_1`, and the result of the command is `None`.

So, the `List_new` in the following code: `List_new = List_1.append(List_2)` will be `None`.

I think the following code will do the trick:

```
List_1 = [item for item in range(1, 161)]
List_2 = [item for item in range(1, 100)]
List_new = []
for i in List_1, List_2 :
    List_new.extend(i)
print(List_new)
```

Answer (score -3):

While you use the append method, used **for** method like this,

```
for i in List_2 :
    List_1.append(i)
```

Now you can print List_1 and also check the length. You will get the right one.